# Create an expression to get a sub element from entity, using a Xtext DSL

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I'd like to know, how can I create a DSL, using Xtext.
This is my code, that I created:

```
Model:
    (entities += Entity)*
    (access += Acessing)*
;

Entity:
    'entity' name = ID '{'
        ( variables += Variable )*
    '}'
;

Variable:
    'var' name=ID
;

Acessing:
    'use' (entity = [Entity])'.'(variable = [Variable])
;
```

The code is a little bit incomplete, but in this way I'd like perform this operation as follows:

```
entity user {
    var name
    var phone
    var address
}

use user.phone
```

I understand that I can use this tag `[Entity]` as a identifier from a specific element, but I don't know how can I get those sub elements from it.

How can I procede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `name`attribute for `Entity` and `Variable`. This is a special attribute which Xtext automatically uses to create namespaces and delivers a working scope provider for free. Elements are identified by their qualified name. You need only a single reference to access them.

To solve your problem, you only have to modify your `Use` grammar rule and introduce a rule which describes a qualified name. Your grammar then could look like this:

```
Model:
    (entities+=Entity)*
    (access+=Acessing)*;

Entity:
    'entity' name=ID '{'
    (variables+=Variable)*
    '}';

Variable:
    'var' name=ID;

Acessing:
    'use' var=[Variable|QualifiedName];

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*;
```

As you can see, it now uses the `QualifiedName` name to identify a variable. I have just tried it and it works out of the box.

Comment: It works great! Thanks a lot Joko! I don't know how it works, the "QualifiedName", and its "ID" element. In those circustances, Can I identify the parent element from Variable?

Comment: ID is a terminal which is used for element "names", the `QualifiedName` concatinatrs several names devided by a dot. Xtext internally uses it to calculate scopes.

Comment: Xtext generates an EMF Ecore model from your grammar which is used as the AST. Everytime you work with the AST, you work with a standard Ecore model. You can do everything you can do with an Ecore model. To access the parent object of any elemet, simply use `EObject parent = element.eContainer()`. Then you can cast parent to the expected type. If you are not sure use `if (parent instanceof ExpectedType) {...}` to avoid errors.